# Handlebar template to create minimum empty rows if number of object is less than minimum row to show

Tags: handlebars.js

I need to show minimum 5 rows filled with empty contents if number of objects is less than minimum rows to draw.

Ex: Let's say i have 3 objects to populate but I have to draw always minimum 5 rows. So I would like to add 2 rows with empty cells.

Is there any better approach without sending empty object with all properties.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this with existing handlebar helpers but you could write your own to do it for you.

You can find more information on writing your own block helpers [here](http://handlebarsjs.com/block_helpers.html).

**Try this:**

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('min5', function(context, options) {
  var ret = "";

  for(var i=0, j=context.length; i<j; i++) {
    ret = ret + options.fn(context[i]);
  }

  for(var i=0, j=5-context.length; i<j; i++) {
    ret = ret + options.fn({});
  }

  return ret;
});
```